# What happens when calling a unbound function during class definition

Tags: python, class-attributes

I am trying to initialize a class attribute by calling a function. Please see below.
This code works as expected meanwhile it makes me confused.
To my understanding getmemtoto is a so-called unbound function which need to be called with a instance of class T. How could it be called during the class definition?

```
class T:
    def getmemtot():
        output=shell(r"sed -r -n -e 's/^MemTotal:\s*([[:digit:]]+)\s*kB/\1/ p' /proc/meminfo")
        return int(output)
    MEMTOT=T.getmemtot()
```

If I tried to call getmemtot directly I got below errors:

```
>>> T.getmemtot()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method getmemtot() must be called with T instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>> getmemtot()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'getmemtot' is not defined
```

Comment: What is ProcEvent?

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry, I change the class name to T to avoid confusion, but missed that one. already corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `T.getmemtot()` use `T().getmemtot()`.  The difference being `T` is a class object whereas `T()` is an instance of the class `T`.

Comment: I understand T().getmemtot works since getmemtot is a object method. What is confusing me is why inside the class definition T.getmemtot is callable.

Comment: You should use `self` instead `T` while working inside the class like `MEMTOT=self.getmemtot()`. It will solve your confusion.